# On the analysis of Christofides's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Suppose you have even number of vertices, they form as a complete graph denote the graph by $G$. Now, suppose we compute the minimum weight perfect matching denoted by $P$ (so $P$ has alternating edges, i.e. one is a perfect matching and one is not along all the path $P$ through all vertices of $G$). Now, suppose $T^*$ is TSP tour of $G$.

> Show that the inequality is true:
> $$ \operatorname{cost}(P) \le \min \{ \operatorname{cost}(N_1), \operatorname{cost}(N_2) \},$$
>
> where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are any two perfect matchings on $T^*$.

Note that this inequality from the analysis of Christofides's algorithm, [see this nice paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs681/2007fa/Handouts/christofides.pdf).

Comment: The weight of a minimum weight perfect matching is bounded by the weight of any perfect matching, by definition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ahh I got the idea! I thought that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are only 'two edges' of the tour of TSP. with respect to you Yuval, if you Put your answer in answer section, I will check it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P$ is a minimum weight perfect matching, by definition
$$ \operatorname{cost}(P) = \min_N \operatorname{cost}(N), $$
where $N$ goes overl all perfect matchings. In particular, $\operatorname{cost}(P) \leq \operatorname{cost}(N)$ for any particular perfect matching $N$.